# could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, winforms

i am getting the following when i tried to load a pdf file "Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Acrobat, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."
Bag image foramt exception was unhandled

Answer (score 2):

The most common scenario when yoiu get bad image format errors when you try to load a 64 bit image into a 32 bit process

Comment: how to know whether it is 64bit or 32bit image in pdf

Comment: Use ildasm that comes with the Windows SDK. If you open the assembly that you cannot load (or one of it's dependencied), double click on the "MANIFEST" node, then look for ".corflags". Follow this article to understand images formats http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slessard/archive/2010/04/09/types-of-managed-code-assemblies.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing your program on a 64 bit machine? If yes, just allow your application to accept 32 bit assembly as well.

If it is a web program hosted on IIS, you can allow 32 bit assembly from Application pool.
If it is a console application you can change at assembly level.

It is very common error and practically will be fixed with above steps.

Hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to load a 32 bit dll in a 63 bit process or vice versa as munissor said.  You can use PESnoop to determine whether an image is 32 or 64 bit.

Get it from http://www.prestosoft.com/download/plugins/PESnoop.zip